# Suppose a matrix A is nxn, and that v1,v2 are in R^n...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

Sorry, this is my first time posting here, so if my question is worded incorrectly, please let me know. Anyway, I'm studying for an exam coming up, and this is one of the questions that I'm trying to work through.

Suppose a matrix, A, is nxn and that vectors v1, v2 are within R^n. Suppose Av1 = 4v1 and that Av2 = 7v2. Show that {v1,v2} is a linearly independent set of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $v_1,v_2$ are not independent, then each one is the scalar multiple of the other, say $v_1=\alpha v_2$, where $\alpha\neq 0$. This means

$$Av_2=7v_2\Rightarrow Av_1=7v_1$$

contradicts the assumption $Av_1=4v_1$

Comment: Ohh, right! Because for an equation to be linearly dependent, they're simply multiples of one another! Duh. I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose they are linearly dependent, then there are constants $c_1,c_2$ so that

$$
c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 = 0
$$

Actually, because you are only dealing with two vectors, you can say this differently: there is $c \neq 0$ so that

$$
v_1 = cv_2
$$

What does this tell you if you compare $Av_1$ and $Av_2$ in two different ways: using what you know about eigenvalues, and using the fact that $v_1 = cv_2$.

Comment: Well, I think that because $v1$ is equal to $cv2$, because they are not identical, they cannot end up equalling 0, which is needed for linear independence. Is this correct? I'm a bit confused as to how you got to the second equation. Also, could you go into more detail about the Eigenvalues? Thanks!